# Variable is not initialized

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I am a beginner in both android studio and coding in general. I could not find out why my variable is not being initialized. I look up some other similar question that inform me the following :-

```
int a;        // This is a declaration
a = 0;        // This is an initialization
int b = 1;    // This is a declaration and initialization
```

I thought the my code is correct with:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) viewPager
```

Apologized in advance if I am missing/misunderstanding some very basic stuff and I would appreciate every help/advice you guys can give.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup
                                container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity()) ;
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Comment: `ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) viewPager` - you are using the variable you are defining to get do the inialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first examples aren't like this one:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
```

as, that in "simple *int* terms", is the same as:

```
int a = a + 1;
```

You can't use **declare** an object an initialize it with **itself**.

In other words: you can't invoke a method on the object you are in the midst of  **declaring**.